# Does hbase read any thing while writing the records.?

Tags: hbase

I am doing analysis on HBase for our application. I am trying to insert the rows from Spark to HBase. I have inserting 7 Million records per batch and observing every metrics.

One interesting thing that struck me while looking through Clouera Manager's HBase UI is, Even though i am writing to HBase, i could see spike for both read and write. I could see the requests in HBase Master UI as well for read & write.

Does HBase read any thing while writing the records.?

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla HBase does not perform a read while doing a write.  That seems bizarre to me.